# Creating a virtual map of devices

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, bluetooth

I'm about to start work on a project, in which the first phase will require me to create a virtual map of all the connected mobile devices within a space (assume they have joined a session of some description and have an auth token from the server). The plan is to use phonegap to create the application.

They should all be accurately positioned (ideally to the nearest 5cm). So far, the ideas I have had are:

**Triangulation using bluetooth signal strength**
Search for bluetooth enabled devices in the area, then send their signal strength to the server so that they may be triangulated relative to eachother. To identify them I was planning on doing a MAC address request.

**Light mapping**
Projecting a light pattern onto the ceiling (or similar flat space) and then requiring the users to take a photo of the map, sending it to the server to calculate their position based on the characteristics of the captured image.

Are these feasible options? Would there be a more accurate or simpler method? Any thoughts or ideas welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bluetooth will not work because the different devices will have different signal strengths so you will have no way to compare them.  The light pattern might work but seems cumbersome.

Why reinvent the wheel?  Sonar has been around a long time.  Emit a ping from a device and time its arrival at the others.  Build up enough samples that you can remove outliers caused by ambient noise.  Extra points if you can use the ambient noise also.  The speed of sound depends on temperature so this method will be more accurate indoors.